# how to use sed command with docker run to replace text on a .conf file for nginx docker image?

Tags: nginx, docker, sed

My `entrypoint.sh` looks like this :

```
sed -i 's/HOST_NAME/'"$HOST_NAME"'/g' /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/CONFIG_FILE.conf

exec "$@"
```

`CONFIG_FILE.conf` is this :

```
upstream gunicorn {
    server $HOST_NAME;
}
```

My docker run command looks like this :

```
docker run -e HOST_NAME=http://cnn.com sid:latest cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/CONFIG_FILE.conf
```

I am trying to pass `cnn.com` via docker run to replace `$HOST_NAME` in `CONFIG_FILE.conf`.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I am new to this, So Please bear with me if I made silly mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288549/passing-variable-from-container-start-to-file

Comment: This Roman, I tried the example from this link,, I am not using env,, I followed the example of setting up the sed command , I think its a syntax issue, cause when I run it , my $HOST_NAME in CONFIG_FILE.conf is replaced as just $ ,, I would have expected to be replaced as cnn.com , but it comes out as empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use other separator than `/` in sed like `#` :

```
sed -i 's#$HOST_NAME#'"$HOST_NAME"'#g' /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/CONFIG_FILE.conf
```